# (Bootstrap) Making columns display uniformly as inline block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a website have a nice set of columns. Right now, unless the text is exactly the same length (and the pictures the exact same height) the site is displaying huge blank spaces. The image below shows some dummy products to test the theme out.

[image]

I haven't been able to get the items to align correctly. This is the loop of HTML to pull products:

```
<div class="container-fluid lg-container">
<div class="row">
<div class="container-fluid">
{bundle = filter(pages, 'product') }
            <div class="row row-body row-margin-bottom no-padding">
            { foreach item in bundle }

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" data-category="view">
                <div class="lib-panel">
                        <div class="lib-header">
                            <a href="#">{{ item.title }}</a>
                        </div>
                    <div class="row xsm-catpad ">
                        <a href="{ item.url }" >
                        <img src="http://xpenology.org/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg" class="lib-img-show img-responsive" />
                        </a>
                            <div class="lib-desc">
                                <p{ item.content }...</p>
                            </div>
                       <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <a href="{{ item.url }}" title="{{ item.meta.title }}"><button class="btn christmas">Check it out</button></a>
                       </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
      </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>
```

Here is some CSS, I hope I included what was needed, but its a big file:

```
.row-body 
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px;
}
.lib-panel {
    margin-bottom: 20Px;
}
.lib-panel img {
    width: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#md-img{
    width: auto;
}
.lib-panel .row,
.lib-panel .col-md-6 .col-sm-6 .col-sm-4 .col-md-4 .col-sm-3 .col-md-3{
    padding: 0;
}

.lib-panel .lib-wide-row {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.lib-panel .lib-header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 300px) {
    .lib-panel .lib-header {
    font-size: 40px;
    }
    .row .row .xsm-catpad{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    }
body {padding-bottom: 125px;}
}

.lib-panel .lib-row.lib-mini-header {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px 0px 0 0px;
}
.lib-panel .lib-row.lib-ad-header {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px 0px 0 0px;
}

.lib-panel .lib-row.lib-desc {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.lib-desc p{
     font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.lib-panel .lib-wide-row.lib-wide-desc {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.lib-panel .lib-row.lib-desc a{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 20px;
}

.row .row .xsm-catpad{
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: First, your `@media` should be last in CSS (there is rules in it that also exists after it, which will make them in the query useless), you have stray elements (a `</section>` with no start tag), please indent your markup and CSS or else it is hopeless to read and detect errors. ... Second, could you post a second image, a copy of the one you posted, that shows how you expect it to look like

Comment: Have a look at [this topic](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height) which walks you through getting same height for the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh, all I needed to do was add this

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

And everything was immediately fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem quite often and usually fix it by displaying the row and columns as flex. e.g.

```
<div class="row flexrow">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     content
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
     content
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.featurerow, .featurerow > col-sm-6{
display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a special class for that. Just add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after each row of columns.

Comment: Implementing this isn't really possible since I was using one row and looping through within that row X times.